# JCalendar multiple day selection

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

Is it possible to select multiple days in toedter's JCalendar? Like I would be able to highlight 2 or 3 days in the calendar and then get the days highlighted after I would trigger an event using a button.

or should i be better off using a JTable for a calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a one column `JTable` having a `JDateChooserCellEditor` and a [custom renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). `DemoTable` is an example, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880675/230513). The `TableModel` should contain a `List<java.util.Date>`, as `Date` implements `Comparable` for easy [sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). You can supply an `addRow()` method in `DemoTableModel`, which can be invoked in your <kbd>Add</kbd> button's handler.