# Java Swing com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar multiple day selection

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

How can I use com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar to have user select multiple dates and get the dates as a result?

Is this even possible using JCalendar?

Comment: What's JCalendar? It isn't in the standard Java class library and googling it shows lots of different things called JCalendar.

Comment: http://toedter.com/jcalendar/

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16420809/230513).