# JDateChooser inside JTable cell enter key does not always work

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, jcalendar

I'm using slightly modified JDateChooserCellEditor class which allows me to put jDateChooser inside my jTable cell. Here is the code of class:

```
    public class JDateChooserCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements
    TableCellEditor {


private JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();

public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

    Date date = null;
    if (value instanceof Date) {
        date = (Date) value;
    }
    dateChooser.setDateFormatString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    dateChooser.setDate(date);

    return dateChooser;
}

public Object getCellEditorValue() {

    dateChooser.setDateFormatString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return dateChooser.getDate();
}
```

One thing does not work and I cannot find a solution. When I click for the first time on a cell that has jDateChooser inside, select date and hit enter key - nothing happens. The component maintains its focus but never confirms data. But if I after that select different cell the enter key magically works and date is saved to my jTable. After another try it does not work.. Next try - it works. It is so confusing. Thank you all for any help.

Comment: the implementation is invalid - a cellEditor _must_ notify its listener when edits are terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found solution for my problem. I think its not the best way but it works and I have lost too much time trying to fix this. Adding listener to jDateChooser component and notifying to stop editing on property change as user kleopatra stated seems to solve the problem.

```
    dateChooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("date")) {
                        stopCellEditing();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thank you all for help.

Comment: that's the way to go, exactly :-) Just beware: it might be needed to not fire when editing starts, in that case the date most probably will be changed as well (don't know the internals of JDataChooser, but our SwingX' DatePickerCellEditor needed to be protected against that)

Answer (score 1):

Your `TableCellEditor` is incorrect. Assuming that your `Table` model stores instances of `Date`, invoke `setDefaultEditor()` as shown with `DemoTableModel`, which is found  in the class `com.toedter.calendar.demo.DemoTable` and illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880675/230513).

```
table.setDefaultEditor(Date.class, new JDateChooserCellEditor());
```

Addendum: Don't set the date format in the cell editor; specify it in the `JDateChooser` constructor or using `setDateFormatString()`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, unfortunately it does not seem to change anything except when I am using default JDateChooserCellEditor it has yyyy-MM-dd date formatting which I should not be using for programs in my country. It is really frustrating that the enter key sometimes works and sometimes not...

Comment: Strange thing is, after typing in/selecting date from DataChooser and pressing TAB button or any arrow key everything works, date gets saved to its cell. There must be something wrong in handling enter key

Answer (score 0):

1. A variation of your answer worked for me

   ```
   private AbstractTableModel model;
   .....
   ... in method getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, final int row, final int column) .....
   try{
       model = (AbstractTableModel) table.getModel();
   } catch( Exception e){};

   dateChooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            String pname = evt.getPropertyName();
            if ( "date".equals( pname)) {
               try{
                   model.fireTableCellUpdated( row, column); 
               } catch( Exception e){};
            }
        }
   });
   ```
2. Super side effect - if you make your table smaller, with your mouse, and the JDateChooser exits the window table (margins are outside the table) while editing, then everything works perfect - no workaround necessary - It is a Swing bug that the refresh is done only when you have to take care of other windows outside you (probably an auto refresh all is called - that's why this bug was not discovered yet)

Answer (score 0):

```
******
yourtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setCellEditor(getDateChooserCellEditor());
or
yourtable.setDefaultEditor(java.util.Date.class, getDateChooserCellEditor());
******

public JDateChooserCellEditor getDateChooserCellEditor() {
    JDateChooserCellEditor cellEditor = new JDateChooserCellEditor(){
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable jtable, Object o, boolean bln, int i, int i1) {
            java.awt.event.ActionListener l = getStopCellEditorActionListener(jtable);
            Component component = super.getTableCellEditorComponent(jtable, o, bln, i, i1);
            JDateChooser dateChooser = (JDateChooser) component;
            JTextField dateEditor = (JTextField) dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent();
            try {
                dateEditor.removeActionListener(l);
                dateEditor.addActionListener(l);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }
            
            return component;
        }
    };
    return cellEditor;
}
private java.awt.event.ActionListener getStopCellEditorActionListener(JTable table) {
    return new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    table.editingStopped(new ChangeEvent(table.getCellEditor()));
                }
            };
}
```