# i want to add jcalendarcombo to the jtable cell

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

code i have used is as follows .. bt it gives classCastException when i click on jcalendarcombo present in jtable cell.
pls help me.. thanks in adv.

```
TableColumn closedDateColumn = resultTable3.getColumnModel().getColumn(7);
            MyDateListener listener1 = new MyDateListener();
            cmbCalanderDate = new JCalendarCombo(JCalendarCombo.DISPLAY_DATE, true); //Calander Combobox for selecting date
            cmbCalanderDate.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));

            closedDateColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(cmbCalanderDate));
            cmbCalanderDate.addDateListener(listener1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `JDateChooserCellEditor` like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880675/261156).

```
closedDateColumn.setCellEditor(new new JDateChooserCellEditor());
```

Another way is to use `setDefaultEditor()`.

```
table.setDefaultEditor(Date.class, new JDateChooserCellEditor());
```